running js on .NET backend
OK, I fully understand that this isn't how you are supposed to do things, but I want to experiment with it anyways.
I have a somewhat large site with .cshtml files. So this is executed on the server and in essence server side rendered, so pretty snappy for the client.
However on this page I have an element that I want to move to svelte.
No big issues, I can build the component outside of .NET, include the bundle and tell it where to render. The only issue with this approach is that this component is not server side rendered.
So I have updated my build configuration to not generate a client bundle, but instead a SSR bundle, which means that I have access to a javascript .render() function that neatly outputs html and css.
So now to the issue and question at hand:
Can I somehow from a cshtml file import this bundle, run the render method, and insert the html output value as html in what is being sent from the server to the client?

cshtml isn't as much server-side rendering as it is templating. Most cshtml directly contains JavaScript and the templating engine typically adds more JavaScript to the HTML result that is sent to the client.

Would maybe look at ClearScript

you can render a CSHTML file to a string using the RazorViewEngine in .NET.
In ASP.NET MVC, you can use the RazorViewEngine to render a view to a string.
Here's an example:
1   Create a Helper Method to Render the View:
Add a helper method in a utility class or directly in your controller.

public string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, object model = null)
{
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    TempDataDictionary tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewPath);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}


Use the Helper Method in a Controller:
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
var model = new MyModel();
string htmlString = RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/MyController/MyView.cshtml", model);
 // Use the HTML string as needed
 return Content(htmlString);

}


